# If $f(3x)=3f(x)$ then what can we say about $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f(3x)=3f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Then what can we say about the function $f$?

Is it continuous? Is it differentiable?

I am trying to see if it is differentiable, If it is differentiable then It will be continuous.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\lim_{h \to 0,n \to \infty} 3^n\left( \frac{f(\frac{x+h}{3^n})-f(\frac{x}{3^n})}{h}\right)$$

But It doesn't help me to go further. I do not think this would help because we have $3^n$ unbounded.

Any Ideas?

Comment: We can't say that $f$ is linear since we are not sure that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ or even $f(ax)=af(x)$.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could provide some context, such as the motivation for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a non-continuous $f$.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if $x=3^n$}, n\in\Bbb Z,\\
0&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee ? $f(1/3)=1/3$.

Comment: Why $f(x)=0$ for non-integer $n?$

Answer (score 7):

There are a multitude of functions $f$ with that property. Indeed, for each real number $x$ in the set $[-3,-1]\cup[1,3]$, you can choose the values of $f(x)$ *arbitrarily and independently of one another*, and there will be a function $f(x)$ satisfying the given functional equation: if $|x|>3$, then recursively define $f(x) = 3f(\frac x3)$, while if $0<|x|<1$, then recursively define $f(x) = \frac13f(3x)$. (If $x=0$ then we are forced to choose $f(0)=0$.)

In particular, it's not necessarily the case that $f$ is even continuous (or measurable), much less differentiable.

Comment: Will your $f(X)$ surject?

Comment: Also, does a similar approach work if $2f(x)=f(2x)$ as an *additional condition* (rather than as an alternative condition).

Comment: That additional condition makes the analysis more complicated/more interesting; but there are still many functions that satisfy both conditions. Define $g(x)=f(x)/x$ (take $x>0$ for simplicity); then you're looking for functions $g$ that satisfy $g(2x)=g(x)$ and $g(3x)=g(x)$. Without making an explicit continuity assumption, though, there are still many possible functions $g$: take a set of representatives $r$ of the quotient (multiplicative) group $\mathbb R_+/\langle2,3\rangle$ and choose the values $g(r)$ arbitrarily and independently.

Comment: Thank-you. I guess there's no representative segment as before, which I was hoping for. I have the Collatz function $g(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)}$ in mind which acts on the same quotient you define of $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ instead of $\Bbb R$ but I can't see how to make this function a subset of a continuous function on $\Bbb R$. This would prove the conjecture via Sharkovski's theorem but there's no obvious way to define $\nu_p$ in $\Bbb R$

Comment: I think you have to exclude one of the endpoints of your intervals. It might be added that instead of your intervals, one could first define such an $f$ on $(-3b, -b] \cup [a, 3a)$ for arbitrary but fixed $a,b >0$; and of course, far more general sets of representatives are possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a somewhat simpler discontinuous $f$:$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
    0,&x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$